# Could the parameter of macro pass to variable of char array?

Tags: c++, macros

The below code has compile error: preprocessor command must start as first nonwhite space

```
#define Assert(expr, format, ...)                               \
if(!(!!(expr)))                                                 \
{                                                               \   
char message[4096] = #format;                                   \
}
```

Please help me out. I want to get the string passed to 'format'.

Comment: You may want to add an example of how you want to use this to your question.

Comment: Please add an example call to `Assert`. Also, you can use `!(expr)` instead of `!(!!(expr))`.

Answer (score 1):

For my money, either there is something wrong before this code, or there are spaces after a backslash, or there is some other non-obvious problem.  When I select the macro in the browser, there are three spaces after the third backslash.  Those formally terminate the `Assert` macro and leave the `#` on the next line to trigger the error. (Outside of a macro definition, the `#` symbol has no meaning in C++ other than to start a preprocessor directive.)

I've added a pipe at the end of each line.

```
#define Assert(expr, format, ...)                               \|
if(!(!!(expr)))                                                 \|
{                                                               \   |
char message[4096] = #format;                                   \|
}|
```

Remove those blanks and watch the error vanish.  Don't allow trailing blanks in your code.

When I place the code copied from the question into a file `pp71.cpp` and try to compile it to an object file (which would be empty), I get:

```
$ g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c pp71.cpp
pp71.cpp:3:65: error: backslash and newline separated by space [-Werror]
    3 | {                                                               \
      |                                                                  
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

That's from GCC 9.2.0 on a MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina 10.15.3.

Comment: That's true. The compile error is caused by spaces. I compiled successfully by removing these spaces. Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.

Comment: @wangsy Pro tip: you can configure most editors to automatically remove trailing spaces when saving a file.